# Calculating difference of 2 layers elevation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1

I want to calculate an aquifer thickness. I have bed rock elevation and also I have elevation of surface of earth. How can I calculate difference of elevation of 2 layers=aquifer thickness by ArcMap?

Comment: If you dont have spatial analyst, install QGIS (and use QGIS raster calculator) or you could use some arcpy and convert the raster to numpy arrays, calc difference and convert back to raster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Spatial Analyst, you can use [Raster Calculator](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm).

[image]

You can do all the mathematical and logical operations here.

Comment: Many Many thanks, I have the Spatial Analysis tools and I did this.

Comment: How I can accept?